# Is there a way to load a .obj file into Pandas or Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, file-type

I have a few .obj files that I want to bring into a dataframe.

I have seen [PyMesh](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but I can't seem to get it to work. It bombs in Anaconda at "load_mesh" not recognized.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This one loads some parts: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/PyWavefront/

Comment: And on gohlke's site you can find a PyMesh wheel.

Comment: Do you just wan't to get the position of the vertices or other attributes as well?

Comment: Just the positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the obj file as an stl file using pymesh OR assimp

Then you can load the stl file using numpy-stl

Answer (score 0):

I use pd.read_csv to read .obj file into dataframe

```
obj_df = pd.read_csv("filename.obj", header=None, delimiter=' ')
```